# Setting statement_timeout on a role correctly in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Assigning a `statement_timeout` to a role in postgres does not appear to persist the setting.

Example:

```sql
-- Set the statement_timeout on a role
alter role api_user set statement_timeout = '500ms';

-- Start a transaction
begin;
    -- Assume the role
    set role api_user;

    -- Display statement_timeout setting
    show statement_timeout;
    -- |--------------------------|
    -- | statement_timeout (text) |
    -- |--------------------------|
    -- | 0                        |
    -- |--------------------------|
```

Since the `statement_timeout` for `api_user` was set to 500ms I expected `500ms` as the output. Instead, it shows the default `statement_timeout` of 0, or unlimited.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is persisted, but assuming the role with `SET ROLE` or `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` doesn't set the parameter.  You have to log into the database as role `api_user` for that.